# "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' "

Tags: node.js, angular, ng-modules

My project was completely running fine but I don't how, when, Where What happened that it's giving error

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

and also

> 1. If 'mat-error' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-error' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

[image]
I have already imported FormsModule and it wasn't giving error before but I don't why it suddenly started giving this error.

[image]
Also include into imports array

[image]
Error showing. I have already inserted the angular material as well as all the necessary imports

[image]
Also included FormsModule in app.component.spec.ts

Comment: Please post your code here as text and not an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is in images, which means it can't be searched by people who have the same question as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have lazy loaded modules, for them you need to import `FormsModule` in the related module, not in the `app.module`. try to import them in `EventRegiterModule`.

If it's Angular 2+ you should use `[ngModel]="Email_id" (ngModelChange)="Email_id = $event"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="Email_id"`

Comment: I tried that too. But it's not helpful still getting the same error.

Comment: as it angular 1 or 2+? in 2+ you should use `[ngModel]="Email_id" (ngModelChange)="Email_id = $event"`

Comment: it's angular 9.1.7. And it was totally running fine during the whole project. And now it's not.

Comment: And by trying your method it's giving error "core.js:36228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:36228)"

Comment: Also I have installed "ngx-webstorage"  lastly (also included it in imports array "NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot()" ) I hope it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: it's hard to say without debug information where the issue is, in my answer there's no `id`, so I think something deeper fails.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Only debug. Add more screenshots with new errors here, perhaps it can bring light to the issue.